# ModuleNotFoundError or ImportError When Installing Python Packages to Conda Env That Require Pip

Tags: python, conda, splinter

While this may be pretty straightforward, I want to share a solution to an issue I was having since I did not have a problem with this until now.

Essentially I was having trouble running `splinter` in my conda virtual environment. I first activated my environment `conda activate PythonData`. Then I tried to run `conda install splinter` which failed, then `conda install -c metaperl splinter` which also failed.

I then moved onto using `pip`, so I went to the documentation and ran `pip install splinter`.

The installation said it was successful, but after restarting the kernel I was still receiving the same error.

See below the solution :)

Comment: How did the installation fail?

Comment: @AMC The installation didn't fail, it said requirement already satisfied but then the import failed because it was automatically getting downloaded outside of Anaconda, even though Anaconda is in my environment variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked through my anaconda bins and did not find the package. Then I realized when I try to install a second time (after ensuring my environment was indeed activated), I saw it was installed in my `usr` folder - not my `anaconda3` folder.

Therefore, I had to run `pip uninstall splinter` to remove it, and then did the following:

`conda install pip` to first install pip (which I used previously with no errors so this is puzzling, but such is life)

`conda info` to find my active environment path

After copying the active environment path similar to the following `/anaconda/envs/venv_name`, I was able to run the installation like this:

`/anaconda/envs/venv_name/bin/pip install splinter`

And then viola! It worked.

Comment: _I looked through my anaconda bins and did not find the package. Then I realized when I try to install a second time (after ensuring my environment was indeed activated), I saw it was installed in my usr folder - not my anaconda3 folder._ That's really bizarre, could there be an issue with Conda/Anaconda?

Comment: @AMC It's really bizarre! I'm not entirely sure, but this worked for me on a Mac

Comment: @AMC I found a solution - I don't need to reinstall Conda.. this was an issue with 10 of my students as well on varying machines.